# How to logged In on a web page where i've already logged in manually

Tags: python, authentication, cookies

I have a page where I have already logged in manually, I would like to open that page from python but it asks me to log in again, which is difficult since you need a YubiKey to log in on that site.
is it possible to take the cookies from that page and log in without entering the data?

I've tried to grab cookies but it didn't work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To capture cookies, you can use a tool like Burp Suite which allows you to intercept HTTP requests and view the cookies being sent. Once you have the cookies, you can use them in your Python script to authenticate. Here's a basic example:

```py
import requests

# Replace with your target URL
url = 'https://www.example.com'

# Replace with your captured cookies
cookies = {
    'name': 'value',
    'name': 'value',
}

# Send a GET request with the cookies
response = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies)

# Print the response
print(response.text)
```